# Area of intercepted geometry

Tags: qgis, geometry, area, intersect, aggregate

I have a polygon layer and a point layer (which was created by obtaining the centroid of each polygon in the polygon layer). I have tried to use the aggregate expression to automatically fill a field in the point layer with the area of ​​the polygon which contains each point and I have not been able to. I have tried it from the fields calculator and from the default options in the layer properties on the form tab.

I tried:

```
aggregate (
 layer: = 'POLY',
 aggregate: = 'concatenate',
 expression: = $ area (intersects ($ geometry, geometry (@parent))),
 )
```

and

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'POLY',
 aggregate:= 'concatenate',
 expression:=area(geometry(@parent)),
 filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
 )

but the expression:
intersects ($ geometry, geometry (@parent))
returns true or false. How can I return a property of the intercepted geometry, in this case the area.
```

NOTE: I know there are many simpler ways to achieve my goal, I even have it solved by calculating the field in the polygon layer and then joining the attributes by field value or location, selecting only the area field. But for future occasions I would like to automate the process, so that when a new point is created, it will obtain not only
attributes of other layers with which it intercepts but also the area of ​​the geometry that it intercepts.

Comment: Hi! The filter is ok. The expression must calculate the area of the child geometry (`area($geometry)`), because the parent geometry is the point, which doesn't have an area. The concatenate function expects strings instead of numbers, but might be converted on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

In the *aggregate* function, the *parent* features are those of the layer in which the function is being written (the points layer in this case).
The *child* features are those of the layer on which the features that are comply with the filter are aggregated (the polygons layer in this case).
So, the solution was to compute the area of the child features geometries (`area($geometry)`).

The final expression, rounded to 2 decimal places, looks like this:

```
aggregate (
  layer: = 'POLY',
  aggregate: = 'concatenate',
  expression: = to_string(round(area($geometry), 2)),
  filter: = intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
  )
```

Comment: Just edited your answer to include information about _parent_ and _child_ features in _aggregate_ function.